# Angular-ui Bootstrap Typeahead control and ng-keydown

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, bootstrap-typeahead

In my application I have a form with this behavior: the form field values are incrementally uploaded to the server after an input loses its focus or user hits Enter. It is done by hooking on lost-focus (custom directive) and key-press (`ng-keydown`) events. At the same time I am using Angular-ui Bootstrap Typeahead control for a city lookup (and some other fields too). The inputs look like this:

```
<input type="text" name="city"
ng-model="dispatcher.city"
ng-keydown="dispatcher.inputKeyPress($event)"
typeahead="obj.city as obj.city for obj in lookup('city', $viewValue)">
```

The inputs without the typeahead work fine, but when it comes to the city input, it works like this:

1. The user starts typing city, e.g. Lon
2. The typeahead displays pop-up with suggestions
3. User selects London and presses Enter
4. The typeahead fills the input with London but shortly after that is the input
   value changed to Lon a that is the value sent to the server.

I suppose that the keypress event results in two actions: typeahed processes its way and at the same time `ng-keydown` interprets it its way. It seems to me, that either typeahead should “consume” the event and not to let it “go further on”, or the `ng-keydown` callback should know if the typeahead suggestion is displayed (so that it could “skip” certain events).

I have played with `typeahead-on-select="onSelect($item, $model, $label)"` but I was not able to sync those two callbacks (`inputKeyPress` and `onSelect`) somehow – the key-press seems to run sooner.

Any suggestions how to accomplish any of these? Or perhaps anything else completely?

Thanks

Besides this the Typeahead is a wonderful control.

Comment: Are you looking for the ability for the user to enter values not present in the typeahead?

Comment: That ability is there already, user can choose from typeahead suggestions or enter a new one. - that works fine. I just cannot synchronised it with the other callbeck (key-press).

Comment: Are you binding the typeahead to an actual value on your model? (ng-model)?  That may be the problem.. otherwise, maybe you can disable the on lost focus for just this form field?  I have bound keypress AND keydown so that I can track that, but that does not appear to e what you need.

Comment: Thank you Trenton for your effort. I somehow feel that the way I built the form is not the right direction and I am going to change it completely. This seems to be too complicated to carry on and I suspect there would be further problems on the way. Thanks again.

Comment: NP... always happy to try to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing your keydown event hook at all, for me it looks like you don't need it really. Your logic should be triggered on select event of typeahead and on lost focus, you will track value change in all cases.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the tip Alex, I gave it a try. The thing is that there are other inputs in the form without typeahead with the “enter-to-save” logic. I want to keep the logic consistent across the whole form. When I got rid of the key-press hook on the typeahed input and used onSelect instead it worked fine for cases when user could select an option from typeahead suggestions. But when entering a new value then the “enter-to-save” logic failed because onSelect was not triggered and the new value was not saved after enter. The lost focus would do it but then the form behavior is not consistent.